# How to query multiple documents from multiple nested subcollections in firebase firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 3 subcollections nested under one another under one single main collection.

I want to get all the documents under 'colection3' for each document in 'collection2' for each document in 'collection1'

I want to query something like -

```
admin.firestore().collection('collection1').doc('FOR ALL DOCS IN COLLECTION 1').collection('collection2').doc('FOR ALL DOCS IN COLLECTION 2').collection('collection3').get()
```

My question is, can I make such query ? Will following query work ?

```
collection('collection1/*/collection2/*/collection3')
```

Is this a valid path? What does "*" indicates?

I tried something like this,

```
const baseRef = admin.firestore().collection(`collection1/*/collection2/*/collection3`);
const querySnap = baseRef.get()
```

It returned me a querySnapshot but when I tried to loop through this querySnapShot, it didn't print anything

```
querySnap.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.id))
```

output was nothing.

I was expecting that doc Ids should get printed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with [collection group](https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries) level queries.

The collectionGroup option returns all documents within the collection group you have created.

```js
const allDocsQuery = admin.firestore()
  .collectionGroup('collection1');

await allDocsQuery.get().then((snap) => {
  // do operations with your data
});
```

Note that you will need to create a collection group in order to use this - it will throw an error with a link to the creation page, but you can also do it by following the documentation in the link above.

Comment: `*` is not a wildcard in collection path and `collection()` is not a `collectionGroup()` query.  The link you've attached has it explained.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Corrected error, although is it now not technically considerable as a wildcard similar to SQL's `*` wildcard that "selects all of x from y" where x is each subcollection of the collection group y?

Comment: `collectionGroup('collection3')` is what OP would require assuming the nested collections have same name in all documents. `*` is not a wildcard when is comes to defining colllection path.

Comment: Yes. I tried collectionGroup('collection3') and it worked. But, What if I want a specific document from 'collection3' from a specific document in 'collection2'?

Comment: Filtering your results is talked about in detail in the documentation linked above.